# I'm Trying to access HTML form data in Python Django,

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I am trying to access HTML form data. I'm struggling to write views for this.

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control"id="inline"placeholder="Username">
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="pass"></i></div>
    </div>
    <input type="email"class="form 
    control"id="example"placeholder="Password">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
```

Comment: POST or GET-Form?

Comment: I'm trying POST Form

Comment: What did you try? Where are you "struggling"? Have you read the tutorial, which is very clear?

Comment: I am trying to access HTML form data. I am struggling to write views for access forms data

Answer (score 0):

For a POST-Form you can do something like this:

Create a
**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
     first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
     last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
```

Then make a view(request):

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm

def formView(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
         #Do Something If Form Is Valid
    return render(request, "form.html", {'form': form})
```

In your Html-File, so in my example form.html, you can get it with:

**form.html**

```
<form id="contact_form_post" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.first_name }}
{{ form.first_name }}
<div class="form-actions">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#views.py
class YourView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = model
    template_name = 'your.html'
    form_class = YourForm

#forms.py
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('yourfields')

#models.py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    yourfields= models.CharField/IntegerField/ForeignKey/ManyToMany


#your.html
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" class="form-control"id="inline"placeholder="Username">
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="pass"></i></div>
    </div>
    <input type="email"class="form 
    control"id="example"placeholder="Password">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Choudhary, try adding some description to your answer by explaining it